# How to send multiple mails with dynamically generating pdfs attachment in codeigniter using php?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, codeigniter

```
public function multisalarySlippdf_mail(){

$file = 'Salary Slip'; 
$pdfFilePath1 = FCPATH . "uploads/".$file.".pdf";
 if(file_exists($pdfFilePath1)){ 
   unlink($pdfFilePath1);
                        }
$this->load->library('m_pdf');// load mpdf library 
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'abc@gmail.com', 
        'smtp_pass' => 'pccpl525', 
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'newline' => '\r\n',
        'crlf'  => '\n',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE

                        );
$salaries  = $this->report->fetchAlldata();// fetching salary data from 
                                           database using report model

foreach($salarie as $sal){ 
$emailid = $sal->official_email; // fetch email ids from the database
if(!empty($emailid)){
$html = $this->load->view('admin/salarySlippdf',
['salaries'=>$sal,
'workingDays'=>$working_days,
'present'=>$present,
'absent'=>$absent,'extraday'=>$extraday,],true);
}
$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath1, "F");// saved file in given path
$subject = " Salary Slip";
$message = "Please Download file".' '.$emailid;
$this->load->library('email', $config);
//$this->email->clear(TRUE); 
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('xyz@gmail.com');
$this->email->to($emailid);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->attach($pdfFilePath1);
if($this->email->send()){
   echo "send"; 
}
else{
 show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}unlink($pdfFilePath1);
}
}
return redirect('admin/report/salaryslipmail'); 
}
```

My code is sending mail perfectly but there is problem in attachment. In mail attachment one employee received his salary slip but second employees also received the first employee attachment(same) two times in one mail and third employee also received the same attachment three times. I don't know where is the problem in my code.
I have little bit knowledge of Php.
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: generate PDF and save it first. then attach those in the mail. once mail sent delete the files

Comment: I am saving file  first then attached but it does not work. :(

Comment: When you are generating the pdf save it to dir and also save the pdf link into database like - create a new column salarayslip(VARCHAR) in employe table and save the uploaded link by employe id  then when you are sending email you can easily fetch the pdf link per employe to attach in mail).

Comment: Not working still

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncomment:

$this->email->clear(true);

This method clear email data and attachments form prev email.
So, it'll fix problem with 1,2,3,4.... attachements, also I think it'll fix problem with same file - because files have same path.

*From docs:*

Initializes all the email variables to an empty state. This method is intended for use if you run the email sending method in a loop, permitting the data to be reset between cycles.

Also, it's bad paractice to load library in the cycle, so better place '$this->load->library('email', $config)' after '$config' defining

Comment: I uncommented $this->email->clear(true); It fixed the problem of 1,2,3,4 attachment but not same file problem. Still same file is receiving on mail

Comment: i put the if(file_exists($pdfFilePath1)){ 
                            unlink($pdfFilePath1);
                           } after $this->email->attach($pdfFilePath1); and before the if($this->email->send())
                       {

                        echo 'Email send.';
                       } but still not working, same problem facing.

Comment: try to reset $html variable: foreach($salarie as $sal){ $html = ''; ....

Comment: put $html = ''; in the beginning of the foreach

Comment: i used the unset($html); after the saving file $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath1, "F"); but not worked :(

Comment: Could you print $salarie array and post here?

Comment: i put the $html variable: foreach($salarie as $sal){ $html = ''; same problem occured.

Comment: [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#65 (68) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["employee_id"]=>
    string(6) "263P16"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(15) "MR.DEEWAN SINGH"
    ["middle_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["full_name"]=>
    string(15) "MR.DEEWAN SINGH"     etc.

Comment: Hm... change $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath1, "F") to $content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');  
$this->email->attach($pdfFilePath1); to $this->email->attach($content , 'attachment', 'report.pdf', 'application/pdf');
And comment unlink in the end

Comment: I saved the file path in foreach loop with employee id and load the  mpdf library then create mpdf object then write html . $file = '';
     $file = 'Salary-Slip'.$sal->employee_id;
     $pdfFilePath="";
     $pdfFilePath = FCPATH . "uploads/".$file.".pdf";
     
      $this->load->library('m_pdf');
     
           $mpdf = new mPDF();
     $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
     $mpdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");

Answer (score 0):

```
public function multisalarySlippdf_mail () {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $month = $this->input->post('month');
    $year = $this->input->post('year');
    $employee_id = $this->input->post('employee_id');
    $department = $this->input->post('department');
    $wihoutemail = $this->input->post('wihoutemail');
    $this->load->model('Report_model', 'report');


    //new modify code...
    if ($month > 9) {
        $e_Setupdate = $year . '-' . $month . '-01';
    }
    else {
        $e_Setupdate = $year . '-0' . $month . '-01';
    }
    // end here ............

    if (!empty($employee_id)) {

        $salaries = $this->report->find_oneemployee_ids($employee_id);
    }
    else {

        $salaries = $this->report->find_employee_id($department);
    }


    foreach ($salaries as $sal) {

        if (!empty($wihoutemail)) {

            if ($sal->official_email <> '' OR $sal->personal_email <> '') {
                goto end;
            }
        }

        $mon_dat = $this->report->find_all_monhtlydata($sal->employee_id, $month, $year);

        $n_data = $this->report->find_pay_ledger_data_oneemployee($sal->employee_id, $month, $year);
        $m_data = $this->report->find_workingdays($sal->employee_id, $month, $year);
        $esetup_data = $this->report->find_basicpay($sal->employee_id, $e_Setupdate);

        if (!empty($esetup_data)) {

            foreach ($esetup_data as $setup) {


                if ($setup->code == 'BSCRT') {
                    $basicpay = $setup->amount;
                }
            }
        }


        switch ($month) {
            case "1":
                $month_txt = "Jan" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "2":
                $month_txt = "Feb" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "3":
                $month_txt = "Mar" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "4":
                $month_txt = "Apr" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "5":
                $month_txt = "May" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "6":
                $month_txt = "jun" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "7":
                $month_txt = "Jul" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "8":
                $month_txt = "Aug" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "9":
                $month_txt = "Sep" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "10":
                $month_txt = "Oct" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "11":
                $month_txt = "Nov" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            case "12":
                $month_txt = "Dec" . '-' . $year;
                break;
            default:
                "";

        }

        $d = [];
        $k = 0;
        $negative = $positive = [];
        foreach ($n_data as $data) {

            $d[0] = $data->code;
            $d[1] = $data->amount;
            if ($d[1] >= 0) {
                array_push($positive, $d);
            }
            else if ($d[1] < 0) {
                array_push($negative, $d);
            }
            $k++;
        }
        if (!empty($m_data)) {
            foreach ($m_data as $mdata) {
                $leave_days = $mdata->leave_days;
                $working_days = $mdata->working_days;
                $present = $mdata->present_days;
                $absent = $mdata->absent_days;
                $extraday = $mdata->extradays_inholiday;
                $additionalday = $mdata->additional_days;
                $weekoff = $mdata->week_off;


                $dojDaysDiff = 0;
                $this->load->model('Income_model', 'income');
                $doj = $this->income->find_employementdetails($sal->employee_id);
                $dojDays = date_diff(date_create($doj->joining_date), date_create($e_Setupdate));
                if ($doj->joining_date > $e_Setupdate) {
                    $dojDaysDiff = $dojDays->format("%a");
                }


            }

        }
        else {
            $leave_days = 0;
            $working_days = 0;
            $present = 0;
            $absent = 0;
            $extraday = 0;
            $additionalday = 0;
            $weekoff = 0;
        }
        $max = max(count($positive), count($negative));
        $grossamount = 0;
        $grossdeduction = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++) {

            if (isset($positive[$i])) {
                $grossamount += $positive[$i][1];
            }

            if (isset($negative[$i])) {
                $grossdeduction += $negative[$i][1];
            }


            $data1 = array(
                'salaries'       => $sal,
                'positive'       => $positive,
                'negative'       => $negative,
                'max'            => $max,
                'month'          => $month_txt,
                'grossamount'    => $grossamount,
                'grossdeduction' => $grossdeduction,
                'leaves'         => $leave_days,
                'workingDays'    => $working_days,
                'present'        => $present,
                'absent'         => $absent,
                'extraday'       => $extraday,
                'basicpay'       => $basicpay,
                'additionalday'  => $additionalday,
                'weekoff'        => $weekoff,
                'dojDaysDiff'    => $dojDaysDiff
            );
            $html = $this->load->view('admin/salarySlippdf', $data1, true);

        }


        $file = '';
        $file = 'Salary-Slip' . $sal->employee_id;
        $pdfFilePath = "";
        $pdfFilePath = FCPATH . "uploads/" . $file . ".pdf";

        $this->load->library('m_pdf'); // load MPDF library

        $mpdf = new mPDF();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");
        //$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);


        //$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");
        //$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");

        $emailid = $sal->official_email;

        if (!empty($emailid)) {

            $config = Array(
                'protocol'  => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'pccplatiq07@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'pccpl55@Atiq07',
                'mailtype'  => 'html',
                'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap'  => TRUE
            );
            $subject = " Salary Slip";
            $message = $html;//"Please Download file";

            $this->load->library('email', $config);

            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('mohd.atiq07@gmail.com');
            $this->email->to($emailid);
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);
            $this->email->attach($pdfFilePath);

            //$this->email->attach($this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html));                

            if ($this->email->send()) {
                echo 'Email send.';
                $this->email->clear(true);

            }
            else {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
        }
        end:
        unlink($pdfFilePath);

    }
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");

    return redirect('admin/report/salaryslipmail');

}
```

This is complete code for generating salary slip in pdf dynamically and also receiving salary slip on mail. Working perfectly for me. :)